# How to get sympy to display condensed expression

Tags: python, sympy

x+I'm using sympy to compute the Jacobian of a fairly complicated expression, and the resulting expressions are all in terms of the lowest-level symbols that I've defined. However, it would be very nice to have it in terms of some of the higher level expressions. For example, consider the basic snippet below.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y = symbols('x, y')
>>> z = x + y
>>> f = z**2
>>> pprint(f)
       2
(x + y)
```

Here, f is shown as (x + y)^2, but I would like it to be shown as z^2. Is there  a way to do this in sympy?

## Edit

Declaring z as a symbol and then substituting in x+y after the fact allowed me to get the Jacobian in terms of z, but my substitution wasn't able to handle the case when the terms were factored out. For example:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
>>> f = z**2
>>> F = Matrix([f.subs(z, x+y)]).jacobian(Matrix([x, y]))
>>> F
Matrix([[2*x + 2*y, 2*x + 2*y]])
>>> F.subs(x+y, z)
Matrix([[2*x + 2*y, 2*x + 2*y]])
>>> F.subs(2*x+2*y, 2*z)
Matrix([[2*z, 2*z]])
```

Here, substituting x+y for z doesn't work because the expression has been expanded out to be 2*x + 2*y. Can F be rewritten in terms of x+y to make the substitution work no matter how it's been factored?

Comment: Just define z as a symbol? You can substitute a value later if needed.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I made z a symbol and it got me much closer to the solution, so thanks! Now I'm running into the problem described in my edit.

Comment: You can use `F.subs(x, z-y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subs function always works well with replacing symbols; in your case you are trying to replace a sum and that will not work well unless that sum actually literally appears as an argument in the expression tree, e.g. `exp(x + y).subs(x + y, z) -> exp(z)`. So there are two approaches:

1. for a simple relationship like x + y -> z, solve for one of the variables and do the replacement x -> z - y
2. get your expression tree tidied up to expose the sum,

e.g.

```
>>> factor_terms(F).subs(x + y, z), F.subs(x, z - y)
(Matrix([[2*z, 2*z]]), Matrix([[2*z, 2*z]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sympy` shows formulas using symbols.

Here you have two symbols `x` and `y`. `z` is not a symbol. It's an `Add` object.

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
>>> type(z)
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
```

You must create another symbol `z` and when you try to do something to `z`, let's say evaluate, diff etc, you can specify that `z` is `x+y`